# How to extract the first word from a string iteratively

Tags: excel, vba, string, split

I have an export containing some names. These are in column E

I'm trying to iteratively go from the top to bottom of the column

A new sheet should be created if it's a new name

All of the same first-words should be added to the same sheet

**An example of column E may be:**

```
7-ZIP RAR decoder
7-ZIP RAR decoder
7-ZIP RAR decoder
Adobe Acrobat and Reader Arbitrary Code
Adobe Acrobat and Reader Arbitrary Code
Adobe Acrobat and Reader Arbitrary Code
Adobe Acrobat and Reader Arbitrary Code
Adobe Acrobat and Reader Arbitrary Code
Adobe Acrobat and Reader Arbitrary Code
Adobe Security Update for
Adobe Security Update for
Adobe Security Update for
Adobe Security Update for
Autodesk Desktop App
Autodesk Desktop App
Autodesk Desktop App
```

```
Sub robbie()
    Dim K As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    K = 1
    Dim firstWord As String
    Dim w1 As Worksheet
    Dim w2 As Worksheet
    Set w1 = Sheets("Export")
    Set w2 = Sheets("Adobe")
    w1.Activate
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("E:E"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange) 
        v = r.Value
        firstWord = Split(v, " ")(0)
        Debug.Print firstWord
        If InStr(v, "firstWord") > 0 Then
            r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**New For Loop**

```
    For Each r In Intersect(Range("E:E"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        v = r.Value
        If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
            
            firstWord = Split(v, " ")(0)
            Debug.Print firstWord
            
            If InStr(v, "firstWord") > 0 Then

            
            r.Copy w2.Cells(K, 1)
            K = K + 1

            End If
        End If
    Next r
```

**Issue:**
When I change the exact value from "7-ZIP" to "firstWord" it fails with the following error yet the Debug.print prints all the correct first-names in the Immediate console as if the for loop is left open

*"Run-time error '9':
Subscript out of range"*

Comment: My guess is you're trying to `Split` an empty string.

Comment: @BigBen thank you, that solved the issue! I've nested the split within an If statement which checks if it's empty 

"If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
            
            firstWord = Split(v, " ")(0)
            Debug.Print firstWord
            
        End If"

Comment: @BigBen Splitting an empty string is the correct operation. It produces an empty array. But taking the first element of the empty array by (0) is incorrect.

Comment: @rotabor sure, you could also check the `UBound` first but OP's solution is fine and IMO clearer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want this:

```
aaa  13    --> should go to a sheet called "aaa"
bbb  42    --> should go to a sheet called "bbb"
```

So you need to make a new sheet if it doesn't yet exist,
then on that sheet find the first empty cell.
Excel doesn't have a 'clean' way to check whether a sheet
exists - so we will have to assume it exists and catch an error.

All together, the following should do it

```
v = r.Value
firstword = Split(v, " ")(0)
On Error Resume Next
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(firstword)  '' let's assume it's there
If Err.Number > 0 Then     '' no, so create new sheet
  Set ws = Worksheets.Add
  ws.Name = firstword
  ws.Cells(1, 1) = r.Value
  Err.Clear
Else    '' sheet exists already; find highest empty cell
  ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = v
End If
```

Comment: @BigBen This the issue I have at the moment!

I've tried to reference the variable "firstword" outside of the loop as above but it obviously failed as v is out of range

The issue with running it inside an If statement which is nested within a For loop is that it iterates through the whole list using the split function without going to the next line after each one then following the If statement

I'd assume this is because it's a For Each loop and it's going through every solution before proceeding to the next line

I've added the new For loop above

Comment: Also @tinnderbox thank you for your suggestion above. I will try to reuse some of this code when I get to the point when I'm moving the info to another document :)

Comment: Fixed it, I was stating a string instead of a variable in the If statement. Thank you for your help both. @BigBen you did not answer the topic with an answer but instead replied to my question by the looks of thing so I'll have to mark Tinnderbox's as the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Split(v, " ")(0)
```

This is problematic if `v` corresponds to an empty cell: the result of `Split` is an empty array. As you've figured out already:

```
If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
```

or

```
If Len(v) > 0 Then
```

or

```
arr = Split(v, " ")
If Ubound(arr) >= LBound(arr) Then
    firstWord = arr(0)
End If
```